# Theory with finite models only

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be any first order theory with a countable set of axioms.

As we know from Löweinheim-Skolem theorem if $T$ has a infinite model, then it has an infinite model of any cardinality.

I am now interested in the question whether any such $T$ has an infinite model, or if there are theories which force a finite model.

All ideas to finding a an example, forcing a finite model would end up with an essential core of the axioms being something like. 
$$ \forall x,y: x = y $$
This looks sound at the first glimps, but only if you have the default meaning of equality in mind. Even if you add all axioms for a theory of equality (reflexivity, transitivity, symmetry, and functional/predicate consistency), there is still the possibility of using an infinite domain and defining all elements to be equal.

So i'd informally conclude that there is always an infinite model for any theory, as long as it has a model at all, since first order logic cannot model semantic equality.
My question is now, whether someone has a proof of that statement or whether there is a theory that forces finite domains.

Comment: What do you mean by "first order logic cannot model semantic equality"?

Comment: I mean that it cannot express the properties of a relation $R$ s.t. $$I(R(x,y)) = true \iff \text{x is the same domain element as y}$$. (Where $I$ is the Model interpreation function.)

Comment: I don't know what does it mean for $x$ to be the same domain element as $y$.

Comment: Not to mention, that equality is extensional to first-order logic. Two things are equal if and only if they are the same thing. So I really don't know what you're on about in your post. You cannot have two different things to be equal, let alone infinitely many of them.

Comment: Of course you can let two different things being equal. The axioms of equality only force a equivalence relation, think for example of a theory which has only the axioms of equality. Consider a model with domain  $\mathbb N$ and define $$I(x = y) \iff x \equiv y (mod 2)$$ This does perfectly fullfill all axioms of equality, but also has domain elements that are "equal" but not the same (eg 1 and 3).

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because 1 and 3 are different objects. You can of course decide that you are changing standard terminology, but then there is really no point on continuing this discussion.

Comment: With respect to the notion of equality I defined in my question it perfectly is. To recall: a relation that is symmetric, transitive and reflexiv. The thing is, that I want to know whether it is possible to define semantic equality (which is the equality you are talking about) synthactically using **first order** (not natural language) sentences.

Comment: Clearly you have a much better grasp of logic than I do. Good luck.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : some model theorists don't take equality to be part of every first-order language, nor don't they take it to always be interpreted as actual equality in all models. I think that's the point of joeschman

Comment: @Max: I am aware that in the distant past equality was not necessarily part of the logic (e.g. some set theory books from the 60s and 70s define equality from $\in$), but this has passed from the world as far as I know. When I took my first course in model theory, the professor—who is a model theorist, just to be clear—said that equality is always part of the logic with the usual axioms and so on, and if you don't want that, then you can define a "congruence" which is what the OP seems to refer to as equality, and consider the quotient model. So... [citation needed] for your claim.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I know it's not recent but the first model theory book I read had a specific section about equality interpreted "arbitrarily"; but obviously you are right that the most common practice is to not mention it ! (the book in question is "Logique Mathématique", Cori and Lascar); and that unless specifically stated otherwise equality is part of the logic (I was giving the OP a way out ;) )

Comment: @Max: I'd expect French to include equality as part of the very underlying notions. But apparently the need to be different than the rest of the world is more important... or should I say, "quasi-important". ;)

Comment: @AsafKaragila In defense of Cori and Lascar, which I think is a very nice book, their default assumption is that languages have equality with its correct semantics. The section "Models that may not respect equality" begins "Our excursion into this topic will be as brief as possible", and it mostly consists of a proof that we don't really lose any generality by requiring $=$ to have its correct semantics.

Comment: @joeschman The standard semantics for first-order logic **does** require "$=$" to be interpreted in the usual way. Indeed, it's usually even considered a logical symbol, in the same context as $\wedge,\vee,\neg$, etc. This wasn't always the case, but is definitely a feature of *modern* first-order logic. That is: the meaning of the term "first-order logic" has changed over time, and the usage you employ here is no longer the standard one (and I'm not sure it was ever the default one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the standard semantics first-order logic, if $M$ is an structure and $a$ and $b$ are elements of $M$, then $M\models a = b \iff a = b$. To be totally clear, the right hand side $a = b$ refers to equality of $a$ and $b$ as elements of domain of $M$, which is a set.

The symbol $=$ is a logical primitive, not a relation symbol, and it is handled differently. Relation symbols can have arbitrary interpretations in structures, while $=$ is always interpreted as true equality.

So the sentence $\forall x\, \forall y\, x = y$ is true in a structure $M$ if and only if $M$ has at most one element.

Now you may have in mind a **nonstandard** semantics for first-order logic, in which $=$ can be interpreted in a structure as an arbitrary equivalence relation which is respected by the other symbols in the language. In that semantics, it's true that any theory with a nonempty model has an infinite model. But it's important to remember that such a semantics is nonstandard. In particular, since you asked about it, the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem is completely trivial (and uninteresting) in that semantics. If $T$ has any nonempty model, you can just replace any equivalence class in $T$ by an equivalence class of size $\kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$. If you think about this a bit, you'll quickly realize that the only interesting notion of "cardinality of a model" is the number of equivalence classes, i.e. the size of $M/=$, at which point you might as well work with the quotient, in which $=$ has its standard semantics.